# Check if item is already in cart, if yes, then redirect user to checkout without adding product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a wordpress shop, where I sell digital products.

**What the function should do:**

1. User clicks add to cart button.
2. Function checks if the item is already in the cart.
3. If yes: Redirect user to checkout page without adding the product to cart (so the quantity doesn't change, it stays at 1).
4. If no: Redirect to checkout and add product to cart (quantity goes from 0 to 1).

**What the function looks like:**

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'my_validation_handler', 10, 2);
function my_validation_handler($is_valid, $product_id) {
    $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
        if ($values['data']->id == $product_id) {
                $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
                wp_redirect($url);
                exit();
        }
        else {
            return $is_valid;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**What happens:**

When I implement the code in the functions.php of my child theme: (I already have the product in the cart) I click on the add to cart button again, but nothing happens.

If the cart is empty same thing, nothing happens, no reload nothing, I'm still on the products page.

**Important detail:**

I know there is a native WooCommerce function (sold seperately). But I have a custom products page and I don't want a message to appear that says "you already added that to cart".

Since I'm retargeting website visitors, the item is still in there sometimes from their last visit. And a expire session solution also not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following, explanation as comment lines in the code

```php
function my_validation_handler( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Get checkout url
    $checkout_url = wc_get_checkout_url();

    // Set variable
    $in_cart = false;

    // Loop
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $product_id ) {
            $in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // True
    if ( $in_cart ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $checkout_url );
        exit();
    } else {
        // Add product to cart
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
        wp_safe_redirect( $checkout_url );
        exit();
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'my_validation_handler', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day. If you want to redirect to cart instead of checkout I have changed `$checkout_url = wc_get_checkout_url();` to `$cart_url = wc_get_cart_url();`